# Cocos2D 2.0-alpha Templates. Missing kazmath

Tags: templates, cocos2d-iphone, alpha

I just downloaded and installed Cocos2D alpha version.
The template installation is successful, however, when I create a new project I can't build it.
The "kazmath" files are missing which are referred to in a number of files so... I've got a million errors.

I've googled it and I already:

1. Checked the compiler is Apple LLVM, in both the project and the
   target.
2. Tried to include the path on the search paths.

However, I can't even find the files anywhere in the project. What I'm thinking is that they aren't getting copied when I create the project.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get the [cocos2d 2.0 beta](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/download), not the alpha version. I just installed Cocos2D 2.0 beta and its templates, they build fine, kazmath is included.

Run the template installer script as follows:

```
./install-templates.sh -f -u
```

Comment: Done, and I still have the same problem. The templates install fine. I create a new project using the box2d template and the kazmath files are missing. Tried searching for them in the project but they are nowhere to be found.

Comment: I also tried the Box2D template, works and kazmath files are there. You should download the latest Cocos2D again just to be sure, then run the script again. But before you do, manually remove the folder ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/cocos2d to be sure the old templates have been removed. If you previously installed the templates with sudo, and now run the script without sudo, it won't be able to replace the templates.